# Organize DNS service for SAAS customers

Tags: php, web, dns, architecture, saas

This is a first time ever when I'm working on `SAAS` project.

I'm stocked with two questions regarding project architecture:

1. About DNS for users - How I can create DNS records, also how can
   users bind their own domain?
2. Use one place stored backend code without making copies for any new user.

Project backend is developed using `PHP 7`.

Great example is WIX (project that helps users to create beautiful websites just in a few clicks).

After registration you get third-level domain "username.wix.com" or something like that and also you can bind your own domain name. 
Framework backend code is stored in one place (it surely cannot be copied every time for any new user, otherwise service-owners will lost all control on updates and have a lot of unnecessary copies).

So the question is, what should I do to implement architecture like this, backend code is stored in one place, after user registration he get third-level domain and can bind his own domain? Meanwhile all executable code is stored in one place (eg.: SSD) and connected to all users?

Thanks in advance for any information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## This is how I would do it.

### Step 1: Separation

1. The client website pointed to a wildcard DNS A record *.mysite.com
2. Your landing page website mysite.com pointed to mysite.com

### Step 2: Registering User

Register the user via your mysite.com form then store it in your database.
Those 2 sites should probably share the same database.

### Step 3: Render page based on the subdomain.

- Lookup if the domain or subdomain is registered to your database connected to a user.
- Render 404 if not existing.
- Else render the user page.

### Step 4: Custom Domain

You would need to give instructions to your user to create an A record pointing to your public IP and have form to verify and create connection to your database.
Look here for reference https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/domains/add-a-domain/using-existing-domains/connecting-domains#set-up-your-existing-domain-to-connect-to-shopify

Comment: Thanks for reply! One more question: if my customer will have something like his own travel store (and travel magazine) and will be able to register user's at his side, am I right that customer's clients will be able to use his own domain to access my saas service, under which my client is and enter exactly his area?  For example: my clients will be able to create their own travel magazines and post about travels, also have some small online store with threir products, after clients registration they will have their own clients. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is possible. Create a separate table for their users with the main user_id column,
or put it in the same table then add a parent_id column. Just make sure to validate each user login on the domain owner user.